# sql results as one big binary blob string

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I had a table called `test` which contains multiple columns `[id, name, age]`

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW binary_test AS select binary(*) AS binary_str FROM test
```

errors out with `Function binary accepts only one argument`

I know I can call binary like this `select binary(id) from test` which calls it for that one column, but is there a way to get all the data from a table and put it in a binary function?

Comment: Perhaps concatenate the columns together first into a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all columns to a single string before calling `binary`, for example, using `to_json`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW binary_test AS select binary(to_json(struct(*))) AS binary_str FROM test
```